# Giving an id to each acitivity of each application in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

My problem is:
I would give a unique ID to each activity for each existing (noy only active one) application on the android phone.
Have you any idea how?
(sorry for my English im French...)

Comment: Why do you want each Activity to have its own ID? Pourquoi voulez-vous chaque activité d'avoir son propre identifiant? Essayez d'utiliser Google Translate. Il devrait vous aider beaucoup.

Comment: I wish could run any of acitivity of any applications when i want

Comment: You cannot run another app's Activity explicitly unless they have exposed a public intent. You can only start your own app's Activities directly.

Comment: there must be a process: how does the application manager to know which applications are on the phone?

Comment: There is a difference between getting a list of applications, and getting a list of the activities defined by those applications.

Comment: can i identify both ? Activities and applications ?

Comment: Not from your application, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to start an Activity, then you can do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: i know this behavior, i want execute any application, even application which are not mine

Comment: Any application? or any Activity within any application?

Comment: any activity within any application

Comment: This is not possible. You can only start activities in other applications if they have exposed a public intent.

Comment: If you are in the kernel then you can do anything you want, but you're not going to find any publicly documented methods for doing what you want at that level. Once you step into the kernel you are on your own. My only suggestion would be to dig through the Android source code.

Comment: ie ? could you explain please ? Is there a solution in android level ?

Comment: there is no documentation on the kernel?

Comment: I have told you, you cannot do this from the Android application level. This is a security feature of Android. The only way to obtain a list of all activities in all applications would be to gain root access. Im sure there is some kind of documentation on the kernel, but it is not something that Google intends for you to do. The user would require a rooted device, and you would have to be careful not to break anything in the kernel code. This is advanced. All you can do is look at the source code and figure it out.

Comment: I'm not responding to your comments any more. Google it for crying out loud.

Answer (score 1):

As Dheeraj said: "You probably meant the ComponentName". ComponentName is:

> Identifier for a specific application component (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, or ContentProvider) that is available. Two pieces of information, encapsulated here, are required to
>   identify a component: the package (a String) it exists in, and the
>   class (a String) name inside of that package.

Now, you can create an object that contains Package name(unique to the application) + class name (unique to activity). 
So the credit goes to Dheeraj.

Comment: Ok, thanks you. And is it possible to have an activity table of all activity associated to the application ?

Comment: The package name need not be unique. You probably meant the [`ComponentName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html).

Comment: Just to clarify: the componentName allows it to recognize an application that I do not know, ie, other applications, not mine ?